# javascript tests if the entered character string starts with an alphabet

Tags: javascript

I want to test if a character string passed as a parameter
starts with an `uppercase` or `lowercase letter`
between 'a' and 'd'.
I wrote this code but it doesn't work it always gives the content of else

```js
function controler1() {
  var x=document.getElementById("champ1").value;
    if (x.startsWith("a") || x.startsWith("b") || x.startsWith('c')|| x.startsWith('d')|| x.startsWith('A')|| x.startsWith('B')|| x.startsWith('C')|| x.startsWith('D')) {
                document.getElementById("teste1").innerHTML=x+" "+"chaine valide commence par une lettre entre a et d";
            }else{
                document.getElementById("teste1").innerHTML=x+" "+"chaine invalide ne commence pas par une lettre entre a et d";
            }
}
```

```html
<style type="text/css">
        #la{border: 1px solid black; width: 800px;}
</style>

<div id="la">
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="champ1" value=" "><br>
  <input type="button" value="tester" onclick="controler1()">
  <p id="teste1"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have empty space prefixed to your input string because of  -

```
 <input type="text" id="champ1" value=" ">
```

Change this to -

```
 <input type="text" id="champ1" value="">
```

You can use `regex` to avoid so many `if` conditions -

```
/^(a|b|c|d)/gi.test(input)
```

```js
 function controler1() {
   var input = document.getElementById("champ1").value;
   var satisfies = /^(a|b|c|d)/gi.test(input);
   if (satisfies) {
     document.getElementById("teste1").innerHTML = input + " " + "chaine valide commence par une lettre entre a et d";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("teste1").innerHTML = input + " " + "chaine invalide ne commence pas par une lettre entre a et d";
   }
 }
```

```css
 #la {
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 800px;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="la">
   <br>
   <input type="text" id="champ1" value=""><br>
   <input type="button" value="tester" onclick="controler1()">
   <p id="teste1"></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please remove the `value` attribute from your input text box. And the demo I have created works right? What part is not working?

Comment: thank you very much for your help, now it works the problem that my browser is blocked and when I exit and open another time it works

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```js
champ1.oninput = () => {
  var res = /^(a|b|c|d)/gi.test(champ1.value); // case insensitive
  console.log('Starts with a/A, b/B, c/C or d/D: ' + res);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="champ1">
```

Comment: @noor uchiha You're welcome. Please, accept and/or upvote my answer if it helped you (you can accept one answer only, but you can upvote both). Thanks!